# HyperOpt: Finding the best modeling based on precision or f1 score

Tags: data, data-science-model, hyperparameter-tuning

I have been using the hyperopt for 2 days now and I am trying to create logistic regression models using the hyperopt and choosing the best combination of parameters by their f1 scores. However, eveywhere, they mention about choosing the best model by the loss score. How can I use the precision or f1 scores instead?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The fmin function is the optimization function that iterates on different sets of algorithms and their hyperparameters and then minimizes the objective function. In Hyperopt we try to find the parameters which minimizes the loss. So if you have evaluation metrics that needs maximizing like accuracy, F1 score we change the sign so that minimizing is equal to maximise the evaluation metrics.

So lets say you use f1-score, you need to maximise you pass negation so that minimizing it will maximise it

```
F1 Score = 0.89  Loss = -0.89

F1 Score = 0.91  Loss = -0.91
```

Negation make sure your hyperparameter which maximises F1 score 0.91 are chosed though Hyperopt minimized it.

Also, if you have metrics like RMSE, MAE which needs to minimised you don't need to flip it.

Comment: so how do you do this for precision?